# Access MainWindow widget from another class gtkmm

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I now developed a small application with gtkmm. My application consists of two classes, a class for my window (mainwindow) and another class that will retrieve running processes on my machine. mainwindow my class contains a List widget.

```
class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
    public:
    MainWindow();
    virtual ~MainWindow();

    bool displayStatus(GdkEventCrossing* event, std::string message);
    bool hideStatus(GdkEventCrossing* event);

    List m_list;
    ...other widget
}
```

I wish I could fill this list from my other class with thic code. But when I try to access my_list I get an error :
`error: m_list was not declared in this scope`

`row` (`Gtk::TreeModel::Row`) is passed as an argument to my function

```
PROCTAB* proc = openproc(PROC_FILLARG | PROC_FILLSTAT);

 while (proc_t* proc_info = readproc(proc, NULL)) {

    row[m_list.m_col_tid] = proc_info->tid;
    row[m_list.m_col_ppid] = proc_info->ppid;
    row[m_list.m_col_cmdline] = proc_info->cmd;
    row[m_list.m_col_utime] = proc_info->utime;
    row[m_list.m_col_stime] = proc_info->stime;

    freeproc(proc_info);
 }

 closeproc(proc);
```

How can I access a widget mainwindow my class from another class?

Answer (score 0):

Generic solution:

```
class B;
class A
{
    public:
        void fillByOtherClass(const B& b)
        {
             b.fill(list_to_fill);
        }
    private:
        List list_to_fill;

}

class B
{
    public:
        void fill(List& list) const
        {
            //fill it
        }
}
```

Usage:

```
A a;
B b;

a.fillByOtherClass(b);
```